# Reading UDP connection information from a process?

Tags: c#, udp

So I am currently using Process Monitor https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon.

And it has a neat function. It can show "Network Activity" and you can then filter by process name, dateTime, operations (UDP Send, UDP Receive, TCP Send, etc.), paths (From IP:Port->To IP:Port), etc.

> 17:52:47.4203171, CMD.exe,    1,  UDP Receive, SomePC.modem.box:1234 -> 123.123.123.123:1234, SUCCESS,    Length: 100, seqnum: 0, connid: 0

Now I am wondering if something like that is possible to do in C#. Because I want to programmatically use the data as it comes in. **I am only interested in the UDP (from->to) sections**. I've searched and I can only find stuff that allows me to read TCP, or UDP without information who the sender is/receiver will be.

Comment: Process Monitor hooks every single network API call.  You can too, but it's much easier to just proxy the connection and copy all the data in both directions after logging (or even modifying) it however you like.

Comment: @MuhKuh What is your question?  I am confused as to whether you do not know how to configure a UDP socket in C#, if you do not know how to query Windows processes in C#, or if your issue is something else.

Comment: @BenVoigt That sounds like what I am looking for. Any direction where I can find this stuff?